# Behat cant click login button in paypal page

Tags: selenium, drupal-7, behat

I am writing test in behat for drupal site. I need to do checkout on paypal page.
I am able to fill in email and password by switch to iframe first. But cant seem to click the login button.

Button seem to get focus but normal click event follow doesnt seem to work as i am not directed to next page.

Comment: make sure the selector is ok and it is a link or button and not a div or anything else. add breakpoints before and after the click, check if the button is not inside an iframe itself.Finally edit your question and add the line from behat that fails and the stack-trace error.

Comment: Add more information in order to see whats failing please... The code you are using and the error shown (if there is an error).